# Elastic beanstalk multicontainer backend not working

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, playframework, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have play application exposing backend on port 9000 and React.js front end wrapped within the same React application which exposes UI on port 3000. Whole application is deployed using dockerfile:

```
FROM hseeberger/scala-sbt:11.0.10_1.4.7_2.13.4

RUN apt-get --allow-releaseinfo-change update
RUN apt-get install -y unzip xvfb libxi6 libgconf-2-4 gnupg2
RUN apt-get update
#RUN apt-get clean

# Installing tools to build node packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential


#Installing docker-ce dependencies
RUN apt-get install -y ca-certificates gnupg-agent software-properties-common
RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | apt-key add -
RUN add-apt-repository \
       "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | \
       tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list

# Installing nodejs
RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash -

# Install g8, which unfortunately requires Java 8 to install
# https://github.com/foundweekends/giter8/issues/449
RUN apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates wget dirmngr gnupg software-properties-common
RUN wget -qO - https://adoptopenjdk.jfrog.io/adoptopenjdk/api/gpg/key/public | apt-key add -
RUN add-apt-repository -y https://adoptopenjdk.jfrog.io/adoptopenjdk/deb/
RUN apt-get update && apt install -y adoptopenjdk-8-hotspot
RUN PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/adoptopenjdk-8-hotspot-amd64/bin:$PATH && curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/foundweekends/conscript/master/setup.sh | sh && ~/.conscript/bin/cs foundweekends/giter8
RUN export PATH=/root/.conscript/bin:$PATH && g8 --version
RUN apt remove -y adoptopenjdk-8-hotspot
RUN add-apt-repository -r https://adoptopenjdk.jfrog.io/adoptopenjdk/deb/

# Install docker
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y docker-ce docker-ce-cli
RUN docker --version || true


# Install Node.js and npm
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN node --version || true
RUN npm --version || true

# Install protobuf & protoc-gen-grpc-web plugin
RUN apt-get install -y protobuf-compiler
RUN protoc --version || true

# jq for parsing config from secrets/cloudflow
RUN apt-get -y install jq

# Install kpt
RUN curl https://storage.googleapis.com/kpt-dev/latest/linux_amd64/kpt --output ./kpt
RUN chmod +x ./kpt && mv ./kpt /usr/bin
RUN kpt version

# Creating Home Directory in container
RUN mkdir - p /usr/src/app

# Setting Home Directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copying src code to Container
COPY . /usr/src/app

# Compiling Scala Code
# RUN sbt compile

# Exposing Port
EXPOSE 3000
EXPOSE 9000
# Running Scala Application
CMD ["sbt", "clean", "compile", "run"]
```

I'm also having nginx with the following configuration:

```
upstream frontend {
  server play:3000;
}

upstream backend {
  server play:9000;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://frontend;
  }

  location /api {
    client_max_body_size 200M;
    client_body_buffer_size 200M;
    proxy_pass http://backend;
  }
}
```

It works fine locally when I run it with the following docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  play:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
    volumes:
      - .:/app
  nginx:
    depends_on:
      - play
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - '80:80'
```

I'm having two containers running properly and whole application works as expected:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS             PORTS                                                  NAMES
eb5c29b5f361   danamex-app_nginx   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   55 minutes ago   Up 8 seconds       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp                      danamex-app_nginx_1
368ddb6f8fec   danamex-app_play    "sbt clean compile r…"   55 minutes ago   Up 8 seconds       3000/tcp, 9000/tcp                                     danamex-app_play_1
```

However, when I deploy the same application to elastic beanstalk using same docker-compose, play application doesn't expose ports:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                               NAMES
e2186d4f1745   current_nginx       "/docker-entrypoint.…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp   current_nginx_1
96dccefba9a7   jeremycod/danamex   "bin/danamex -Dpidfi…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute                                       current_play_1
```

I don't see anything from EB logs. There is no indication that something was wrong with the application.

```
play_1   | Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
play_1   | [[37minfo[0m] play.api.Play - Application started (Prod) (no global state)
play_1   | [[37minfo[0m] p.c.s.AkkaHttpServer - Listening for HTTP on /0.0.0.0:9000
nginx_1  | 2021/09/11 22:36:01 [error] 30#30: *43 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xxx.xx.2.40, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.19.0.2:3000/", host: "xxxxxxxxxx.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com"
nginx_1  | xxx.xx.2.40 - - [11/Sep/2021:22:36:01 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36" "24.85.210.60"
nginx_1  | 2021/09/11 22:36:01 [error] 30#30: *43 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xxx.xx.2.40, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.19.0.2:3000/favicon.ico", host: "xxxxxxxxx.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com", referrer: "http://xxxxxxxxxx.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/"
```

I've tried to change instance to t2.large in order to validate that it's not running out of memory.

Any idea what could be the problem?